# Overloading magic methods with IronPython

Tags: c#-4.0, ironpython

I'm attempting to define the power operator ** in a C# class (we'll call it class Foo).  I've overridden `__pow__()`, which gets me the desired behavior for operations of type `Foo ** int`.  Unfortunately, I need to also define `int ** Foo`, and neither using dynamic values nor overloading `__pow__()` gives me the desired behavior; I always receive the error `unsupported operand type(s) for **: 'int' and 'Foo'`.  I have successfully overridden C#-recognized operators using the operator keyword; both `Foo / int` and `int / Foo` are functioning successfully.  Is there any way to do this with `__pow__()`?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you overload `__rpow__` also?  (Probably doesn't have anything to do with this question)

Comment: jaco219 probably has the correct answer.

Comment: Jcao219 does indeed have the correct answer!  Thanks for the assistance.